# Yii Email Validation Failed

Tags: php, validation, email, yii

I have an email validation, that should be work to validate email.
True condition is: example@ext.com or dash12@ext.com or as_sa@ext.com
Another are wrong.
So I have this code on function accessrules on the model:
[image: Email Validation Failed]

But when I tried to register, it said error, although I have entered the right format.
This is my error
[image: Email Validation Failed]

I have tried to fix it but still error. Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks all

Comment: Please Note: I was considering using this functionality, and it's all set up correctly, and works most of the time, but unfortunately it fails randomly (certainly with Ajax-triggered validation.)
The caveat "may fail due to temporary problems" should read "will fail randomly for very-well-known domains, but will work if you repeat the validation." (!) I haven't looked into the source code, but I'm assuming it's just looking up the MX record, so basically checking whether the domain name part of the email address has an associated email server. The validation has failed for me for e.g. hotmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**checkMX** is to check the MX record for the email address. Defaults to false. To enable it, you need to make sure **the PHP function 'checkdnsrr' exists in your PHP installation**. Please note that this check **may fail due to temporary problems even if email is deliverable.**

Answer (score 0):

You should put your email validation script in model rules not in accessrules of controller.
try this

```
  array("email","patern","your regex for validation","message" => "Email is not correct"),
```

put this array inside your model rules function array this will work for you.

Comment: thanks, I already put it on my model, and I found the error, I just delete the 'checkMX'=>true.

Comment: What is this checkMX?